# Will yoga practice make previous body problems reappear?

Tags: yoga

It's a theme I keep hearing repeatedly from Yoga teachers: when you start Yoga for first time or after a long pause all past body ailments will somehow reappear for some time (supposedly until you "really cure" them through practice). Is there any proof of this?

Comment: Actually, some teachers even give a "spiritual" dimension to meeting again your old problems.

Comment: Edited the question trying to make it less prone to subjective opinion...

Answer (score 3):

The explanation is air-y fairy nonsence.

The 'ailments' are just another way of describing DOMS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_onset_muscle_soreness

Answer (score 0):

Yoga is to heal, and to make you internally strong. It is to cure some ailments, and I have never heard of such claims where it says past problems would re-appear. Though western medicine and fitness industry may not approve what yoga claims, but if you look at its origin, it has originated in Far East  and people from that part of the world get many benefits out of it. It's all about using natural ways to get better, improve circulation, breathing, flexibility, get stronger and above all, achieve internal peace and calmness.

Having said that, everything has a way to get things done and ways to do them right. The former one is the shortcut that may fetch some benefits, but risks are always there when it's not done right. So when you start things after a while, make sure you are doing then right. May be that's what their concern is, that you may have lost the right way to do things which may create problems for you. Other than that, I don't see how things could go wrong if done right.